# MATLAB - Select a row in a struct-array by the condition struct.field = 'someValue'

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

Can someone explain me how is the right syntax for conditional column selection for structures in MATLAB ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what it is you are looking to do? It's not clear to me what you think of as a column, and the title says row.  Include the full question in the body, don't let us try and combine information from the title into your question, it leads to misunderstandings. Some code helps clarify things where language could be ambiguous.

Comment: Please show us some example data and explain what you would like the result to be.